# Sending mail programatically is not working

Tags: java, gmail-api

I have written the following code in order to send mail.
Previously it worked but now it isn't working anymore.
Can somebody please help me with solving my problem?

```
public void send(String to, String subject, String msg,final String user,
            final String pass) {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new GmailAuthenticator(user, pass));

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

        String msgBody = GetUserPassword(userid);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);

        // 3rd step)send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any Exception or what means `not working`?

Comment: it is throwing an exception saying that org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)

Comment: Please add the whole stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use the new "enable less secure apps" setting in Gmail.  Using an oauth2 token (with either SMTP MSA or the Gmail REST API) is preferable to storing + using a password and won't require disabling that security check in Gmail.